# ADF angular framework dashboard adfWidgetAdded event doesn't fire

Tags: javascript, angularjs, events, dashboard

I'm using adf framework dashboard (https://github.com/sdorra/angular-dashboard-framework/) in my application, but I can't implement the adfWidgetAdded event because doesn't fire.

I saw ADF sdorra examples where it works, but I can't find the problem.

There is no documentation for that.

Can anybody help me?

HTML Code:

```
<adf-dashboard name="{{dashBase}}" collapsible="{{collapsible}}" structure="6-6" adf-model="model"/>
```

JS code:

```
$scope.$on('adfWidgetAdded',function(event,name,model,widget){
        console.log('adfWidgetAdded',name,model,widget); //Never enter
    });
```

Comment: are you using JS code in dashboard controller?